# Visualize data with Google Calendar

Tags: php, javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm building a web page where I dynamically load some events I want to show in a calendar. I also want users to be able to import these to google calendar.  So I thought the easiest thing to do was to work with the [Google Calendar API](https://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/calendar/).  But it's just not that simple...

Thing is you can't dynamically give events that the calendar widget... only exsiting google calendars, or by refering to an ics file (which should then be created on my server).

It should be possible to create a new google account, and create new calendars on the fly. After creating them I should be able to pass the URL to the widget.

But I don't really fancy any of those solutions.  I would rather just pass the data to a widget, then if people wanted, it could be imported to google calendar.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

(Right now my web skills only come down to PHP and JavaScript, so taht's what I'm using)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a Google account programmatically. However, the API does allow you to create a new secondary calendar on an existing Google account, and set/control the ACL list for it. Perhaps that's what you want to do.

Comment: yeah that's what I meant.  But this is really a lot of trouble, so I've done something else instead